# C# String format, add characters to string

Tags: c#, string, binary, format, character

I have binary number in string which is for example 10 and I need to format this string that it looks like this: 00000010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string binary = "10";
string newBinary = binary.PadLeft(8, '0') //it returns a new string after padding chars, so you'll have to store it somewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

> ```
> numberToFormat.ToString("00000000")
> ```

Comment: No you can't do this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake, you can format number (e.g. int) to string